# Windows 7 changes from aero to basic simultaneously on two computers in the same network

Tags: windows-7, aero

So me and my girlfriend have two computers in the same network.

Our computers just switched to aero basic at the exact same time, and then returned to normal aero almost same time aswell. Our computers weren't in the basic aero for very long, about 2-5 minutes or so.

We both had chrome on at that time, and steam aswell. Otherwise no same programs running.

Now this isn't a big problem really, but I'm wondering why it happens.

This has happened before aswell, and it happened back when I lived alone, and with older computers too.

Comment: Do you remember that time a requester came up saying, the 3D is being worked (well it doesnt say it like that) and it can switch aero off to basic so the 3D is not used up by aero and the transparency.  That requester also has a "dont ask me just do it" (well not exactally) switch you could select to allow windows to manage that whenever it desired.  While that usually is about tough to render games, any program (inc browsers) using the 3D rendering methods could cause the system to do  that.  Which just leaves how to turn it back to asking you first. (that i do not know yet).

Comment: I didn't get any popups, it just simply happened. No warnings, nothing. Only thing I had on at the moment was Chrome and Youtube video playing in it.

Comment: It can also occur when winsat does a assesment of your hardware, that is triggered via the task scheduler. you could look in there and see if the time corelated.  that would also explain both of them hitting at the same time.

Comment: Will do when I got time, thank you for your help :) I will edit my findings to main post

Comment: Also check the Windows event-logs for around the same time.